# Problem with open dns

Tags: opendns

I'm running windows 7. And I have also installed the open dns updater. Configured the IP Version 4 to  use the dns  server 208.67.222.222.
But everytime I reboot or shutdown then turn on the computer. And open my open dns account via the browser. It detects another IP and I have to add this new network again so that I can have open dns. What might be wrong?

Comment: Sounds like your ISP uses dynamic IPs.

Why don't you just change your DNS settings in the network configuration control panel? You certainly don't need software to use openDNS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you click the **Update Now** button on the GUI, does it update what you see in your account on the website?  Is the tool/service even running in the background when you start your computer?

[image]

**Check all the logon details** are correct for the account in the updater, including the network name if you have one.  **Re-enter your password** just to make sure.

Do you have any firewall/internet security software that may be blocking the updater from sending the updates?  If so, try temporarily disabling it and see if it updates.

Have you tried uninstalling, restarting and then reinstalling the updater again?

Failing that, give [**DNS-O-MATIC**](https://updates.dnsomatic.com/) a go instead.

> DNS-O-Matic provides you a free and
>   easy way to announce your dynamic IP
>   changes to multiple services with a
>   single update. Using DNS-O-Matic
>   allows you to pick and choose what
>   Dynamic DNS services you want to
>   notify, all from one easy to use
>   interface.